# Is there a way to uniquely identify a column via jdbc? I do not mean via schema table column

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, internals

I am trying to track changes made to a database (schema) using a java app. We are trying to track changes for each column/unique-constraint/index and table.
Functionally I know table.column is unique. So, if the datatype of a column changes, we know which column to find and record the change. But what if the name changes? If **JDBC's result set is ordered (it asks for index)**, then I can rely on the order to give me the same column everytime, even if the name changes. Will there be any surprises here, since it is a result 'set'?
However, I learnt that **we can change the order of the columns** as well. Isn't there any **unique ID associated with the columns** so that they can be picked up on that basis?
I would mostly not want to use information_schema route, but even though i checked there for mysql, found nothing useful.

Comment: There is no such thing in JDBC. If such a thing exists (which I doubt), you will need to dive into database system specific metadata.

Comment: One could argue that simply re-ordering the columns is not a meaningful schema change unless the code that interacts with the database implicitly relies on the ORDINAL_POSITION of the columns by doing something silly like `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( ... )`.

Comment: @GordThompson, that is why the intent to capture change is mentioned. If lets say columns a,b,c,d change to w,x,c,d and then to x,w,c,d.. I'll compare a,b,c,d to x,w,c,d and might end up altering a to x. I suppose there is no way around this, except somehow capturing every DDL.

Comment: @ChinmayJoshi - I think you may be right, at least for MySQL. Microsoft SQL Server supports DDL Triggers that might be able to track the column changes as they occur, but MySQL apparently does not support DDL Triggers.

Comment: We are going to ignore order changes for now. Thanks.